# Is it possible to save a file to an exact, specific location? (Windows 8.1 Universal App C#)

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

**What I need to do:**

Save an image file to an exact, specific location when the app is run (Let's say "Z:\test\photo.jpeg").

**Additional wanted functionality:**

1) Overwrite the file ''Z:\test\photo.jpeg' if it already exists.

2) Skip the write, if the folder 'Z:\test\' doesn't exist.

What I've already tried:

```
using Windows.Media.Capture.UI;
using Windows.Storage;


CameraCaptureUI camera = new CameraCaptureUI();
StorageFile photo = await camera.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

if (photo != null)
{

    var targetFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("photo.jpeg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    if (targetFile != null)
    {

        await targetFile.DeleteAsync();
        await photo.MoveAndReplaceAsync(targetFile);
    }

}
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to get the variable 'targetFile' to point to a particular location, eg. "Z:\test\photo.jpeg"?

I don't want to use local app data folder, pictures folder, or anything like that. It needs to be this particular location.

Comment: If I understand your question right. You can have a look at [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I had a look and SpecialFolder doesn't exist as a part of System.Environment for 8.1 apps

Answer (score 3):

Univeral Apps are sandboxed and can only access their on storage folders.

You can grant access to other files using [FileOpenPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207847) or [FolderPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207881), but you won't have control about what file the user picks for you to write into.

This means you have to make your user pick that exact file for you to store at, otherwise your app can't access that location.

Here's an overview on [accessible file locations for UWP apps on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Comment: For the pickers, Is it possible to have SuggestedStartLocation set to my specific path? ("Z:\test\")? I can't find it anywhere in the documentation, it only seems able to accept a preset series of common locations (My Pictures folder, etc), rather than a custom file path

Comment: Nope, only the items in this list are supported: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.pickerlocationid

Comment: Frustrating, but an understandable security decision, I suppose. Thank you